# Html agility Pack how to get the text from all the nodes except one specific

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I have a html document that is made out of

```
<title>Something</title>
<p>Text1</p1>
<p>Text2</p1>
<p>Text3</p1>
...
```

I want to get the text from it without the Title element.I want to extract only:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

Do you know how I could do that?

Now I am doing it like this:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

                doc.Load(MyFile.html);

                var stringWriter                        = new StringWriter();

                AgilityPackEntities.AgilityPack.ConvertTo(doc.DocumentNode, stringWriter);

                stringWriter.Flush();

                document.DocumentContent                = stringWriter.ToString();

                return document;
```

*document is the method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it alot harder for yourself than it has to be.

Load the document as a `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
```

Either use `Load()` or `LoadHtml()` to load the HTML into the document object.

As an example, the following which has five paragraphs.

```
doc.LoadHtml("<title>Something</title><p>Text1</p><p>Text2</p><p>Text3</p><p>Text4</p><p>Text5</p>");
```

To only get the three first paragraphs, select them all and iterate over them:

```
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            HtmlNode node = nodes[i];
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }
```

which results in the printout

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```